# to_number from char sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to select only the IDs which have only even digits (an ID looks like: p19 ,p20 etc). That is, p20 is good (both 2 and 0 are even digits); p18 is not.

I thought to use substr to get each number from the IDs and then see if it's even .

```
select from profs 
where to_number(substr(id_prof,2,2))%2=0 and to_number(substr(id_prof,3,2))%2=0;
```

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? It sounds like you already have a solution in mind and just need to try to implement it.

Comment: What do you mean when say "has only even numbers". It should consist of only 0 2 4 6 8 or whal number should by even . for example '10' - should be included or not?

Comment: for exemple f20 is good because 2,0 are even nr but p18 is not good because 1 is odd

Comment: my question is how to select the ids which have only even numbers

Comment: @emma_soraya - 18 IS an even number. What you mean is that EVERY DIGIT must be even. I will edit your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IF you need all rows consist of 'p' in beginning and even digits on tail It should look like:

```
select *
  from profs 
 where regexp_like (id_prof, '^p[24680]+$');
```

Comment: thank you very much...i used select * from profs where regexp_like (id_prof, '^[24680][02468]');

Comment: @emma_soraya - does this mean all the numbers (not considering the p) are EXACTLY two digits long? If not, your solution will miss p8 and also p200, because it requires EXACTLY two even digits after the p. Michael's solution was more general.

Answer (score 2):

```
with
     profs ( prof_id ) as ( 
       select 'p18' from dual union all 
       select 'p24' from dual union all
       select 'p53' from dual
     )
-- End of test data; what is above this line is NOT part of the solution.
-- The solution (SQL query) begins here.
select * 
from   profs
where  length(prof_id) = length(translate(prof_id, '013579', '0'));


PROF_ID
-------
p24
```

This solution should work faster than anything using regular expressions. All it does is to replace 0 with itself and DELETE all odd digits from the input string. (The '0' is included due to a strange but documented behavior of `translate()` - the third argument can't be empty). If the length of the input string doesn't change after the translation, that means the input string didn't have any odd digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
where mod(to_number(regexp_replace(id_prof, '[^[:digit:]]', '')),2) = 0
```

Comment: it says missing expression